# Jquery passing text to selector Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html code :

```js
//Now I want to get html of div tag with id=answer[0] when click a tag 



$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  var id = this.id;
  var id1 = id.replace("[", "\\\\[");
  var id2 = id1.replace("]", "\\\\]");

  var newS = "div#" + String(id2);

  alert($(newS).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="radio" id="answer[0]">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="opt1"><input type="text" placeholder="Answer" name="answer1[0]"></label>
  <a href="#" id="answer[0]">x</a>
</div>
```

It shows message "undefined" . Why not show html div tag ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using same id for multiple elements. Id should always be unique you can use same class for multiple elements. Anyways, to make your code work just use two "\" instead of four. This works:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  var id = this.id;
  var id1 = id.replace("[", "\\[");
  var id2 = id1.replace("]", "\\]");
  var newS = "div#" + String(id2);
  alert($(newS).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="radio" id="answer[0]">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="opt1"><input type="text" placeholder="Answer" name="answer1[0]"></label>
  <a href="#" id="answer[0]">x</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```js
//Try this 

$('#click').on('click', function() {
    alert($('#answer').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="radio" id="answer">
  <label>
   <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="opt1">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" name="answer1[0]">
  </label>
    <a href="#" id="click">x</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the HTML, you need to use `html()`, which you have used correctly, but it needs to be used with the DOM selector. Your replace patterns are incorrect and hence it not working for you. Instead of 4 `\`, you only need 2 `\`. And secondly, you can chain `replace()`:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  var id = this.id;
  var id1 = id.replace("[", "\\[").replace("]", "\\]");
  var newS = "div#" + String(id1);
  console.log($(newS).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="radio" id="answer[0]">
  <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="opt1"><input type="text" placeholder="Answer" name="answer1[0]"></label>
  <a href="#" id="answer[0]">x</a>
</div>
```